# Create simple graphic with HTML

Tags: html, rows, graphic

I need to create a little graphic with HTML for a Java project. Unfortunately, this is the first time I'm using HTML and I don't know how to do the following graphic:

[image: This is the graphic]
Looks like I have to split each row into two columns, but after trying a lot of things, I'm not able to do that.

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you want a lib or make it yourself?
It must be in full HTML? or you can draw it with canvas?

Comment: As always... please post what you have tried.

Comment: @Crocsx I want to make it by myself, full HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use a HTML table. Lots of how to's available on the net.

Im not going to write it for you, but something like this might help you getting started.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Test1</th>
    <th colspan="2">Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Testdata1</td>
    <td>Testdata2</td>
    <td>Testdata3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```